# If I'm using Workgroup based Windows networking, do I need a login for all users on all PCs if I have a guest account with Admin Priv?

Tags: security, windows-xp, windows-7, guest

I administer our small office network.  If I want PC's 1-5 (PC1, PC2, etc.) to all have access to our Server (using Windows Workgroup networking (not Domain networking) that I have to have the logon for each user (from PC1, 2, etc.)  on that server.

If I have a Guest account on the server, does that give each user access to whatever the Guest has access to (without needing to have all those duplicated logons?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously - remove guest from the admins group - in fact disable the guest account. You are just asking for trouble.

You really have two options to do this correctly.

1. Setup a domain and use domain authentication
2. Manage the accounts on the "server" - that is the only place you need multiple accounts unless the people log into multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

The Golden Rule of system administration: All accounts should have the minimum access rights that are required for that account to do the job required of it.

As for having guest in the admins group - **DON'T DO THAT** - Ever! The guest account really shouldn't even exist but as it does it should be disabled and never used. You really should have proper authentication. If you don't want to set up individual accounts, either local or AD, you can (but really shouldn't) create one generic account and have your users all use that. Of course when (not if) something gets screwed you won't have any way to determine who did it. Be aware that this issue could even have legal ramifications.